# Preserve property case in DTO

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp

I was wondering if there is any way to maintain the case for the property name. What I am doing is sending response from Spring controller to JSP page as a DTO object. While doing so spring creating JSON object by changing case for the property name.

DTO

```
class MyDto { private Long DT_RowId; .... }
```

Controller

```
class MyController {
   public @ResponseBody MyDto someMethod() {
      //fill up MyDto object
      return myDto;  
   }
}
```

JSON created and received in JSP

```
{ "dt_RowId": 1, .... } //need to be DT_RowId
```

My question is can I specify in property level to maintain case of the property name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Jackson for JSON formatting and parsing, you can use `@JsonProperty` to specify the JSON property name:

```
public class MyDto {
    @JsonProperty("DT_RowId")
    private Long DT_RowId;

    // ...
}
```